# Pinterest and Klout Twitter Integration

Tags: c#, twitter, linq-to-twitter, klout

I noticed that Pinterest and Klout does there Twitter authenticatio/signin differently and was wondering if people here knew why.

If you sign into Pinterest with your Twitter account, you have to authorize the app. Then if you log out and then log back in again, it asks you to authorize the app again.

However with Klout, you only authorize once. And then if you log out and log back in again with Twitter, it doesn't ask you to authorize again.

My app is asking people to authorize again, which is not what I want. Does anyone know how I can achieve the Klout approach? I am using C# and Linq2Twitter.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

After the first time that you authorize a user, save their credentials. Then, reuse those credentials (for that user) for all subsequent queries.

Comment: On my samples page, I have a Credentials ToString and Load demo that might give you some ideas: https://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=LINQ%20to%20Twitter%20Samples&referringTitle=Home. I receive a lot of requests for demos in all the supported technologies. I'm gradually building up my samples library and plan to cover many different scenarios.